# Universal member-function definition, instanceable from both 'const' & 'non-const' objects

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, mingw-w64

Is there a way to define a member function that is both accessible from 'const' & 'non-const' objects?

I need this for my `sList` implementation of list class. In it I want to declare a function which will take as a parameter another function with either 'const' or 'non-const' pointer to `sList` and will call it for each list in the current `sList` structure.

Here is its declaration:

```
template <typename T>
struct sList
{
    sList(initializer_list<T>);

    inline void DoForEachList(auto pFunc)
    {
        for(auto p = this; p; p = p->pNext)
            pFunc(p);
    }

    ~sList();

    T dat;

    sList *pNext = nullptr;
};
```

I'm using `auto pFunc` because I want to eventually pass lambdas too. So now if I have a const object of this type and call from it 'DoForEachList' passing as an argument lambda function with 1 arg from type 'auto'. My compiler will fail with something like:

> error: passing `const sList<unsigned char>` as `this` argument of `void sList<T>::DoForEachList(auto:1)` [with `auto:1` = `main()::<lambda(sList<unsigned char>*)>`; `T` = `unsigned char`]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

And the code calling `DoForEachList`:

```
void main()
{
    extern const sList<unsigned char> cvobj;
    cvobj.DoForEachList([] (auto pCurr) {/* Do something */});
}
```

Is there some way I can define the `DoForEachList` member function (or template of member function) like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct sList
{
    inline void DoForEachList(auto pFunc) auto //either 'const' or none
    {
        for(auto p = this; p; p = pNext->pNext)
            pFunc(p);
    }

    //...
};
```

Comment: You could use a friend function template, and maybe two member function wrappers.

Comment: Quite simple - A non-const object can always bind to a `const` reference, but not the other way around. That is an implicit conversion (qualifying conversion) though. Hm. That's useless if you actually want to modify the object if you invoke it on a non-const object though. In that case, just write two functions.

Comment: With the same body - Ugh, is this the best way? Using wrapper function is not a solution because then 'pFunc' argument will be wrongly deduced (if we wrap a 'non-const' call in the 'const' member function using const_cast for 'this' the lambda function arg will be deduced to 'sList *' which is wrong).

Comment: And the same will happen if we wrap the opposite way (a 'const' call in the 'non-const' member function). In this way lambda function arg will be deduced to 'const sList *'.

Comment: I like dyp's solution. Remember, a `friend` function is not a member function and has no `this`. Instead, it would be a plain old parameter passed from the two member function wrappers. You wouldn't need a `const_cast`. One of the instantiations of the friend template would have a `const`-qualified type argument. The other instantiation would not. They would both be const-correct.

Comment: I see - it works but I hoped for a more elegant solution.

Comment: **`void main()`**?  Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only the `const` member function and make the member variable `mutable`, which tells the compiler/you that the member does not influence the "has-been-changed" behaviour of the class. If this is not the case, rethink your design, because this is not quite right. `mutable` is more correct where e.g. a map's key needs to be modified in such a way that it does not influence the ordering in that map, but even then...

Code example:

```
struct Bla
{
    void increment() const { i++; }
private:
    mutable int i = 0;
};

int main()
{
    const Bla bla;
    bla.increment();
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c7d2e715bff4074).

Answer (score 6):

To build upon the answer by @dyp in the comments:

You do indeed need two separate functions if you want to overload on the constness of `this`. However, you can minimize duplication by offloading the work to a helper function.

@dyp suggested using a friend function template for this, but friend functions have no access control, so I would normally prefer a static member function instead; you can then make it private or protected:

```
template <typename T>
struct sList
{
    void DoForEachList(auto pFunc)
    {
        DoForEachListHelper(*this, pFunc);
    }
    void DoForEachList(auto pFunc) const
    {
        DoForEachListHelper(*this, pFunc);
    }
private:
    static void DoForEachListHelper(auto&& self, auto pFunc)
    {
        for(auto p = &self; p; p = pNext->pNext)
            pFunc(p);
    }
};
```

Comment: @hvd Thanks. With `auto&&` you could also overload `DoForEachList` on ref qualifiers, not that it makes much difference in this case.

Comment: Yeah, when I noted that it could be `auto self`, that was for my first suggestion where `self` would be a pointer, in which case `&&` isn't useful at all. In this particular case, where `self` is a reference, it still doesn't make a difference since you only call it with lvalues, but it's a simple and useful enough general approach that I can see why you opted for it. :)

Comment: *"friend functions have no access control."* I do not understand what you're trying to say here.

Comment: @dyp If you declare a friend function, anyone can call it, right?

Comment: @hvd Ah, yes. There are ways to emulate private friend functions, but they're not as elegant as directly using access-specifiers, of course.